# How to add multiple items to Accompanist HorizontalPager?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

When I create

```
HorizontalPager(count = 3) {
   page  -> ComposableName()
}
```

It just shows same composable multiple times, i can't add few pages and if I try to

```
HorizontalPager(count = 3) {
   Image()
   Image()
   Image()
}
```

elements are just stacked on top of each other and also 3 times.

Is there any way to make smth like

```
LazyColumn()
{
item {}
item {}
item {}
}
```

If not what's the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `content` block of `HorizontalPager` you get `index` of the page that should be displayed. So you can do something like this:

```
HorizontalPager(count = 3) { index ->
    if (index == 0) {
        Image0()
    } else if (index == 1) {
        Image1()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: God bless you! It was so confusing and unintuitive to figure out on my own! Maybe you could advise some other resources?

Comment: Well Accompanist has many samples that show how to use those components: https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/v0.28.0/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/pager/HorizontalPagerTabsSample.kt#L112

Answer (score 1):

The way to make it works is:

```
val itemPager = listOf(Image1: String, Image2: String, Image3: String )

val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    
HorizontalPager(count = itemPager.size, state = pagerState) { currentPage -> 
     
    Image(currentPage)
}


@Composable
fun Image(page: String) {
     Async...(page)
}
```

In the example, I used Coil. You can use what you want,